# Can't preview Images on IonicView with Android

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Well, I made an app using Ionic Creator, I added two images and finished my app, Iexported it out from ionic with "ionic start [appName] creator:[myappnumber]" and it did all fine.
I used ionic serve in terminal and it pops up a chrome window showing my app, in there the image is showing, but when I did ionic upload and downloaded files in my mobile with ionic view and then wanted to preview my app, the problem is there, the image isn't showing, I already tried with img src= and img ng-src but neither of them works.

```html
<ion-view title="Title">
<ion-content padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header">
    <img ng-src="/img/r7qprdTRXqs2xOvgKLHI_3-logocolor.png" width="100%" height="auto" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
    <form class="list">
        <ion-list>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Nombre</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Usuario</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <a href="#/page1" class="button button-dark button-block ">Iniciar Encuesta</a>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug with using Chrome browser's DevTools. Type "chrome://inspect/#devices" in the url section after running the application on your device. Make sure your device is connected to your computer. Once the app runs, you will be able to see your device on the browser and check if images are loaded. It will be easy to debug. It will be either path issue or layout issue.